# Attach a newline to every sentences

Tags: regex, vim

i was wondering how to turn a paragraph, into bullet sentences.

before:

```
sentence1. sentence2.  sentence3.  sentence4.  sentence5.  sentence6.  sentence7.
```

after:

```
sentence1.

sentence2.

sentence3


sentence4.

sentence5.
```

Comment: New line is not very special when you replace something for it, so more than a regex problem this sounds like a "how do I express my new line so that my regex engine sees it". To solve that we need to know your environment (shell, programming language, OS, IDE ?)

Comment: im trying to do this using vim. and when i add a newline to the end of the period, i just get an error character

Comment: See http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/how-to-set-up-vim-to-work-with-one-sentence-per-line

Comment: This was my solution in Sublime to hopefully cover more complex sentences: https://gist.github.com/Daniel-Hug/0082b179797cfc6c71780b7c79d4048e

Answer (score 11):

Since all the other answers so far show how to do it various programming languages and you have tagged the question with Vim, here's how to do it in Vim:

```
:%s/\.\(\s\+\|$\)/.\r\r/g
```

I've used two carriage returns to match the output format you showed in the question.  There are a number of alternative regular expression forms you could use:

```
" Using a look-behind
:%s/\.\@<=\( \|$\)/\r\r/g
" Using 'very magic' to reduce the number of backslashes
:%s/\v\.( |$)/.\r\r/g
" Slightly different formation: this will also break if there
" are no spaces after the full-stop (period).
:%s/\.\s*$\?/.\r\r/g
```

and probably many others.

A non-regexp way of doing it would be:

```
:let s = getline('.')
:let lineparts = split(s, '\.\@<=\s*')
:call append('.', lineparts)
:delete
```

See:

```
:help pattern.txt
:help change.txt
:help \@<=
:help :substitute
:help getline()
:help append()
:help split()
:help :d
```

Comment: @Al: You may want to use this regex from `:help /character-classes` as it closely mimics "sentences" defined by the `)` command: `[.!?][])"']*\($\|[ ]\)`

Comment: How do you this in vim if you want to do it only on a selection (:'<,'> at the command line)?  This works for me, but only if I want to insert two returns after every line in the file.

Comment: This combined with `gqG` (fit all lines to line width) is great for making a length of text readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace all end of sentences `/(?<=.) /` with a period followed by two newline characters `/.\n\n/`. The syntax would of course depend on the language you are using.

Comment: This worked for one instance, but not every instance.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
perl -e "$_ = <>; s/\.\s*/.\n/g; print"
```

Longer, somewhat more readable version:

```
my $input = 'foo. bar. baz.';
$input =~ s/
    \.      # A literal '.'
    \s*     # Followed by 0 or more space characters
    /.\n/gx;       # g for all occurences, x to allow comments and whitespace in regex
print $input;
```

Using Python:

```
import re
input = 'foo. bar. baz.'
print re.sub(r'\.\s*', '.\n', input)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex

```
/\.( |$)/g
```

That will match the end of the sentence, then you can add newlines.

Or you can use some `split` function with `.` (dot space) and `.` (dot), then join with newlines.

Comment: `.` generally matches any single character in a regex, and should be escaped.

Comment: Sorry, I commented too soon ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An example using Ruby:

```
ruby-1.9.2 > a = "sentence1. sentence2.  sentence3. and array.split(). the end."
 => "sentence1. sentence2. sentence3. and array.split(). the end." 

ruby-1.9.2 > puts a.gsub(/\.(\s+|$)/, ".\n\n")                                
sentence1.

sentence2.

sentence3.

and array.split().

the end.
```

It goes like, for every `.` followed by (1 whitespace character or more, or followed by end of line), replace it with just `.` and two newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
<?php
$input = "sentence. sentence. sentence.";
$output = preg_replace("/(.*?)\\.[\\s]+/", "$1\n", $input);
?>
```

Also, regular expressions are a blast, but not necessary for this problem.  You can also try:

```
<?php
$input = "sentence. sentence. sentence.";
$arr = explode('.', $input);
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) $arr[$k] = trim($v);
$output = implode("\n", $arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

using awk

```
$ awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\n" file
sentence1.
sentence2.
sentence3.
sentence4.
sentence5.
sentence6.
sentence7
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this in RegExr

Search String is

> (\-=?\s+)

--

Replace String is

> \n\n

---

### This is the generated information for the current regex

RegExp: `/(\-=?\s+)/g`

pattern: `(\-=?\s+)`

flags: `g`

capturing groups: `1`

group 1: `(\-=?\s+)`

### This will find every - in the sentence below and replace it with two newlines

> > Sentence 1- Sentence 2-  Sentence 3-  Sentence 4-  Sentence 5-

### The end result is

Sentence 1

Sentence 2

Sentence 3

Sentence 4

Sentence 5

Answer (score 0):

I have a really simple naive solution using capturing regexs.

```
:%s/[.!?]/\1y\r\r/g
```

The main draw back is this won't handle ellipses or multiple punctuation.

Comment: Your regex doesn’t have any capture groups in it? Also, is the `y` a typo?

Comment: that’s quite alright; it’s what the [edit] button is fore