# For selected lines, put each scentence on a new line with vim

Tags: vim

My vim buffer contains lines with more then one sentence.

How can I make each sentence start on an new line? I do not want to insert extra empty lines between sentences that already start on a new line.

I can replace each . by .\n `%s/\./\.\n/` but that insert a new line also when there already is a new line after a sentence.

Edit:
If the line starts with % then I want to leave that line as it is.

Comment: seems to be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956375/regex-attach-a-newline-to-every-sentence-using-vim

Comment: @angezanetti Thanks, the questions are very similar indeed. Only I do not want to insert a new line when the next sentence already starts at a new line. This part is omitted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956375/regex-attach-a-newline-to-every-sentence-using-vim

Comment: it is very hard to be done precisely in vim. It depends on how "complex" your sentences are.

Comment: See discussion here: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/how-to-set-up-vim-to-work-with-one-sentence-per-line

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
:%s/\([?.!]\)\s\(\w\)/\1\r\2/g
```

A lookbehind to make sure the line does not start with a `%` should prevent substitution on those lines:

```
:%s/\(^%.*\)\@<!\([?.!]\)\s\(\w\)/\2\r\3/g
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you add a bit of explanation?

Comment: It replaces the space characters between all sentence ending characters (?.!) and word characters. The captures remember the sentence enders and the first letter of the words. The substitution replaces the space with a newline.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. This forms a good start to learn to build these kind of replacements. Thank you for the update too. Can you also explain the update?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`:g/^[^%]/s/\../.^M/g`

Explanation:

`:g/^[^%]/` work on lines that don't start with %

`s/\../.^M/g` replace every . followed by another character with a newline.

```
"one. two. three." becomes
one.
two.
three.
```

This doesn't keep the character after the full stop.

To keep it, use this:

`:g/^[^%]/s/\../&^M/g`

```
"one. two. three." becomes
one. [trailing space]
two. [trailing space] 
three.
```

To keep it, but on the line following, use this:

`:g/^[^%]/s/\.\(.\)/.^M\1/g`

```
"one. two. three." becomes
one.
 two.
 three.
```

In all cases, to enter `^M`, type `ctrl+V` then `return`